# Limiting Characters per Line in a Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have been searching all weekend for the solution to this quandry and have yet to find a solution that works correctly. What I am trying to acchieve is to limit the number of charatcers per line in a textarea - not limiting them identically, but a different number of characters per line of my choosing.

**For Example:**

1. I want to have only 4 lines in my textarea
2. Line 1,2 and 3 will be limited to 24 characters
3. Line 4 will have an unlimited number of characters

Is this possible with a textarea, or is there another way of doing i with a Div or something. I do realise that this has in all likelihood been covered before, but to find an actual working script that covers this criterium has proved extremely difficult and I don't have the kind of skill it takes to acchieve these results.

Thanks

Comment: If you ask if is it possible, probably. but what have you tried?

Comment: what affect are you trying to go for? if they don't all have to be connected use 4 inputs you can limit them however you want. you could probably even fake with css 4 inputs that look like one and seems like a better solution

Comment: You could split by line break and detect the number of characters. But the issue is that you can't control `lines` per say, that's dictated by font size, letter spacing etc. One line on one machine on a certain OS might be different to one line on another machine with another OS. Ryan's example is a better idea.

Comment: I have tried several scripts, but they were rather old and as such would merely limit the 1st line and throw alerts and errors when attempting to go the second line.

I thin kyour suggestion, ryan, is the best so far ... I will give it a try. 

Thanks

Comment: Ok, it's working perfectly with an auto-tab statement in my onkeyup handler. Now I need to sort out the copying value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a sample snapshot of the problem that you're trying to solve:

- 4 lines in the textarea (Limit this on the textarea itself with rows="4")
- Lines 1, 2, and 3 are limited to 24 characters
- Line 4 will have an unlimited number of characters

**Snapshot of the textarea:**

```
123456789012345678901234
123456789012345678902333
232323232323232323323232
23232323232323232323236464536543654643
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#your-input').keypress(function() {
     var text = $(this).val();
     var arr = text.split("\n");

     if(arr.length > 5) {
         alert("You've exceeded the 4 line limit!");
         event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
     } else {
         for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             if(arr[i].length > 24 && i < 3) {
                 alert("Length exceeded in line 1, 2, or 3!");
                 event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
             }
         }
     }

     console.log(arr.length + " : " + JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

This can be accomplished using a keypress event. When the keypress event fires, get the current value of the textbox and split the value into an array using the `\n` line break character as a delimiter.

- The length of the array tells you how many lines you have. If you've exceeded those lines, we fire an alert.
- The length of each individual string inside the array represents the length of each line. We use a for loop to check the first 3 lines. If we exceed the length of 24, we fire an alert.
- We ignore the last iteration of the loop, since we aren't concerned with the length of the last line.

This is not designed to be a complete solution, but this will definitely get you started and provide you with something that you can modify to suit your needs. Good luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `cols` control width, not lines/height.

Comment: @Daedalus - Thanks :) It's getting close to calling it a night :)  Fixed!

Comment: I realize you've likely gone to bed, but just an alert; it doesn't allow the carriage return character after the limit is reached.

Comment: Hey Jmort253, I hope you don't think me cheaky for asking, but I have tooled around with the script you have supplied me above and have not been able to get it to work. Is it something to do with Json?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that this wasn't tagged with jQuery :( Are you including jQuery in your project? If not, (and you have no qualms about using it) you could place this in the `<head>` section of your page and then rerun the above code. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Also, that solution was only tested in Chrome. It's really just a way to help you get started as there doesn't appear to be an out-of-the-box solution for what you're hoping to accomplish. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The JSON.stringify part is just a convenience method I'm using to actually output the contents of `arr` for debugging purposes. You'd need to use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools (or IE Developer Tools) to see that logger, or change console.log to alert.