# How to restrict number of characters per line in textarea?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have one Ext JS TextArea. There I want to restrict my characters to 15 characters in each line and total number of lines should be not more than 10.

What I am tring to do here is

```
function(){
    var myValue = this.getValue();
    var myValueData = myValue.split(/\r*\n/);
    myValueData.length = 10;    
}
```

Ideally it should ommit all the lines after line number 10, but is not happening. Also how to restrict only upto 15 characters per line?

Comment: Will [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680493/limiting-characters-per-line-in-a-textarea) help?

Comment: I don't want to show the message. I want to the wrap the things.

Comment: You can just remove the alert, the code will still work without it.

Comment: Nope. Text are disappearing.

Comment: Yep, they use js to prevent more text from appearing which mean if you exceed the limit the text won't show. Something like if you type the number 16 character someone will press backspace for you.

Comment: You get your textarea's value, then create sliced copy of it and cut it to 10 lines but don't set textarea's value again, how do you expect it to work? (Remember to join lines into string first). Have you checked `myValueData` value after setting its length to 10?

Comment: @barbsan Can you help me with the code.

Comment: @David Well I already wrote my suggestions, have you tried them? There are many similar questions, I won't add anything new, it's not that hard to translate jquery to vanilla js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give that one a try, not perfect, but should work.

Maybe its be better instead using the change listeners, overwriting setValue or setRawValue functions on the component.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2js1

```
   {
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                grow: true,
                name: 'message',
                fieldLabel: 'Message',
                anchor: '100%',
                listeners: {
                    change: function (cmp, newVal, oldVal) {
                        var arrayForEachLine = newVal.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
                        var newVal = [];
                        Ext.Array.each(arrayForEachLine, function (line, index) {
                            if (line.length >= 10) {
                                offset = line;
                                while (offset.length > 0) {
                                    newVal.push(offset.substring(0, 10));
                                    offset = offset.substring(10);
                                }

                            } else {
                                newVal.push(line);
                            }
                            if (index === 10) return false;
                            if (newVal.length >= 10) {
                                newVal = newVal.slice(0, 10);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        cmp.suspendEvent('change');
                        cmp.setValue(newVal.join('\n'));
                        cmp.resumeEvent('change');
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: the answer looks good. But when you paste something in the field it breaks (doesn't paste everything). And the user's requirement was also to limit the number of lines.

Comment: thanks, changed some details, i guess it should work now

Comment: I didn't check it yer. But all I wanna say is our solutions are pretty similar

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using the change listener. I have created a [demo (fiddle)](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jqg). Please look at the fiddle as the code there is neat and has comments too. Please look at my change listener code below:

```
listeners: {
                change: function () { 
                    var myValue = Ext.getCmp('myField').getValue(); 
                    var lines = myValue.split("\n"); 
                    if (lines.length > 10) { 
                        alert("You've exceeded the 10 line limit!"); 
                        Ext.getCmp('myField').setValue(textAreaValue); 
                    } else { //if num of lines <= 10
                        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { /
                            if (lines[i].length > 15) { /
                                alert("Length exceeded in line " + (i+1)); 
                                Ext.getCmp('myField').setValue(textAreaValue); 
                            } else if (lines[i].length <= 15 && i == lines.length - 1) { 
                                textAreaValue = myValue; 
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Please mark this as an answer if this answer solved your problem as this will also help other people in future. If there is anything wrong with this answer please let me know in the comments. I am sorry if something's wrong as I am not an extjs expert. But I still tried.

Comment: Here's another [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2js6). This version is better but a bit complicated. But the good thing is this even works when you copy and paste a long line.  The fiddle above just works when user is typing stuff.

Comment: I am sorry this is the last, best and final version of the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2js7). Instead of alerts I am logging stuff to the console.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is prefect for regex...

My solution focuses on the **"max char width"** and **"max line number"** requirements which I don't consider to be the same as **"max char count"** due to wrapping on words. Because this solution uses plain regex it works best with plain-text with newline chars `\n` for line breaks rather than html.

This function is idempotent which means it's output can be piped into it's input without issue. It's also very efficient because it's pure regex. Both of these attributes make it perfect for dropping into an `onchange` handler to update text on every key-press without incurring large performance penalties.

```
const fit = (str, w = 80, h = 24) => {
    w = new RegExp(`(?![^\\n]{1,${w}}$)([^\\n]{1,${w}})\\s`, 'g');
    str = str.replace(w, '$1\n');
    h = new RegExp(`(((^|\\n)[^\\n]*){${h}})((($|\\n)[^\\n]*)+)`);
    str = str.replace(h, '$1');
    return str;
};
```

This function will format the string into the given width / height, but it does so in a very *agreeable* way: The wrapping regex is considerate of existing new lines which is why it's idempotent, and breaks lines between words not through them. For an in depth explanation of how the word wrap regex works and why it's robust, see my answer for word wrapping strings in JavaScript with regex:

[Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript/51506718#51506718)

Answer (score 2):

To restrict textarea character length you can use the following attribute maxlength .

```
<textarea maxlength="50">
```

To truncate a string or number.

```
text_truncate = function(str, length, ending) {
if (length == null) {
  length = 100;
}
if (ending == null) {
  ending = '...';
}
if (str.length > length) {
  return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
} else {
  return str;
}
};
```

you can call it by

```
text_truncate(yourContentToTruncate,15);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is using pure JavaScript.

The basic idea is **creating an array of chunks made of 15 characters** with `.match(/.{1,10}/g)` and then, **joining the array with a line break** `join("\n")` to create an string again. The number of lines are restricted just removing the remaining chunks using `splice(10, chunks.length - 1)`.

We are using `.onkeyup` event, but could be another event, that's because the code is not fired until we release a key. But this code also works if we paste text inside the textarea because the event is fired as well.

```js
document.getElementById("textArea").onkeyup = function() {

  var text = this.value.replace("\n", "");

  if (text.length > 15) {

    var chunks = text.match(/.{1,15}/g);

    if (chunks.length > 10) { 

      chunks.splice(10, chunks.length - 1);

      alert("if text have more than 10 lines is removed");
    }

    this.value = chunks.join("\n");

  }
};
```

```html
<textarea rows="18" cols="50" id="textArea">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the place where you are specifying the textarea field, you need to set 'enforceMaxLength' attribute to true and then set 'maxLength' attribute to number of characters as your limit. Please find the following sample code for extjs. In the example i have set the restriction of no more than 10 characters. Hope this helps.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Contact Info',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textarea',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    enforceMaxLength:true,
    maxLength:10,
    allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

for 10 line accept condition

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lines = 10;
    var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');

    $('#countMe').keydown(function(e) {

        newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
        linesUsed.text(newLines);

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
            linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            linesUsed.css('color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can not use jquery. Do you have solution in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the solution which puts cuted characters to the start of the next line. Only 10 lines are allowed, in each line 15 characters.

**Solution with Ext JS**

Unfortunately, snippets on SO do not work with Ext JS.

And because of this you can see it on [this codepen.io link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKzKVE).

```js
Ext.application(
{
    name: 'ExtApp',
    launch: function ()
    {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',
        {
            title: 'Sample TextArea',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Restricted number of characters per line in textarea',
            height: 500,
            width: 700,
            items:
            [{
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                grow: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Please write your text:',
                height: 320,
                width: 480,
                listeners:
                {
                    change: function(self, newVal)
                    {
                        var chunks = newVal.split(/\r*\n/g),
                            lastLineCutedTxt = '';

                        for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++)
                        {
                            chunks[i] = lastLineCutedTxt + chunks[i];

                            if(chunks[i].length > 15)
                            {
                                lastLineCutedTxt = chunks[i].slice(15);
                                chunks[i] = chunks[i].slice(0, 15);
                            }
                            else lastLineCutedTxt = '';
                        }

                        if(lastLineCutedTxt != '')
                            chunks.push(lastLineCutedTxt);

                        self.suspendEvent('change');
                        self.setValue(chunks.slice(0, 10).join('\n'));
                        self.resumeEvent('change');
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-triton/theme-triton.js"></script>
```

**Solution with pure JavaScript**

```js
var txtArea = document.getElementById('txt-area')
txtArea.onkeyup = function(e)
{
    var chunks = this.value.split(/\r*\n/g),
        lastLineCutedTxt = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++)
    {
        chunks[i] = lastLineCutedTxt + chunks[i];

        if(chunks[i].length > 15)
        {
            lastLineCutedTxt = chunks[i].slice(15);
            chunks[i] = chunks[i].slice(0, 15);
        }
        else lastLineCutedTxt = '';
    }

    if(lastLineCutedTxt != '')
        chunks.push(lastLineCutedTxt);

    this.value = chunks.slice(0, 10).join('\n');

};
```

```html
<textarea id="txt-area" rows="16" cols="35"></textarea>
```