# Textarea with max number of lines and max characters per line

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm facing one issue where I need to develop `textarea` where number of lines must be 10 and maximum character per line - 15. **Once the 16th character will be entered it must move to the next line.**

Also we can't enter more than 10 lines. Here's what I am trying to do.

Onchange listener. I'm trying to restrict the user to enter 15 chars, but it's not happening. Below is my code. Any suggestions will be helpfull.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
    title      : 'Sample TextArea',
    width      : 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype     : 'textareafield',
        grow      : true,
        name      : 'message',
        fieldLabel: 'Message',
        anchor    : '100%',
        listeners : {
            change : function(val,b){
                debugger;
                var text = val.getValue();
                var lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm); 
                 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    if (lines[i].length > 10) {
                        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, 10);
                    }
                }
                     text = lines.join('');
                //alert(val.value)
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Here I have asked for number of charactes to each line and number of line is text area.

Comment: pls check this thread u already opened, its basically the same and the answers there look promising i guess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564052/1816139 thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict number of characters per line in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491767/how-to-restrict-number-of-characters-per-line-in-textarea)

Comment: @devbnz Thanks for link and I accepeted the answer there. But here question is different, here I asked about number of line restriction as well in textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, this type of solutions (on change listeners) are prone to complex problems: there are many ways to input content, such as drag-n-drop stuff into the textfield, copy/paste, etc. But here is a somehow working solution with some comments:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
    title      : 'Sample TextArea',
    width      : 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype     : 'textareafield',
        grow      : true,
        name      : 'message',
        fieldLabel: 'Message',
        anchor    : '100%',
        numLines : 15,
        numCharsPerLine: 10,
        listeners : {
            change : function(val,b){
                var text = val.getValue();
                //console.log(text);
                var lines = text.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/); 
                 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    if (lines[i].length > this.numCharsPerLine) {
                        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, this.numCharsPerLine);
                    }
                }
                if(lines.length < this.numLines && lines[lines.length-1].length == this.numCharsPerLine) lines[lines.length-1] += "\n" ;
                lines = lines.slice(0,this.numLines); // limit line number
                 text = lines.join('\n');
                 //console.log(text);
                 this.setRawValue(text)
                //alert(val.value)
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank u for answer. This is working fine but in the end my cursor is going to 16th line. (End of line) let me know if we can restrict that. In case we can not please let me know that also.

Comment: @David I've added a new check before adding the newline. Also, I wasn't sure if you need 10 lines with 15 chars each or 15 lines with 10 chars, so I created the variables numLines and numCharsPerLine to be easier to control/change this